# lftp mirror files from a directory tree into single directory

Tags: mirroring, ftp

I am looking for a way using lftp to mirror files from a remote location that are in a constant directory structure based on date into a single local directory. In wget this is done with --cut-dirs=, anyone have any suggestions here?

Currently my command line is just:

```
lftp -c "connect http://server.com; mirror --use-pget-n=3 bla1/data /n/data/bla/all_the_data"
```

But this recreates the remote directory structure (as it should), but I would like it not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirror command is to copy directories. As you want to copy just the files, you should use `mget` command. E.g.

```
mget -c bla1/data/*.* -O /n/data/bla/all_the_data/
```